# dompdf php to pdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Estou a usar o `DomPDF` para gerar o pdf. A questão é que não consigo converter meu html para pdf. O meu html é gerado por varias linhas de php com variáveis e etc...

Já tentei passar uma variável com tudo para o `DomPDF::loadhtml`, mas, como são tantas linhas de código, não consigo.

Há alguma maneira de gerar o html final e passar para a variável ?

```
// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Get the generated PDF file contents
$pdf = $dompdf->output();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá vc pode usar assim:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.seusite.com.br/seu_html_gigante.php');

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$dompdf->stream();

header('Content-type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
echo $pdf;
```

Caso tenha problemas com session ou algo do tipo, considere utilizar essa outra forma:

```
ob_start();

include_once ("seu_html_gigante.php");

$html = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean()

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$dompdf->stream();

header('Content-type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
echo $pdf;
```

Comment: this works...but now i have the problem that my page can only be seen if im logged in so i get the loginpage even if im allready logged

Comment: I changed to suit your problem @I-amSam

Answer (score 1):

Sim, há. A maneira que conheço de "pegar o html final" é dar um include e capturá-lo no output buffer.

Exemplo:

```
ob_start();

include 'seu_html_gigante.php';

$dompdf->loadHtml(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: tentei..mas deu codigo invalido... o php vem do wordpress...
   require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
   include 'www.toppromomkt.com/?wallet=janeiro-2016-2';


   // reference the Dompdf namespace
   use Dompdf\Dompdf;

   // instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(ob_get_clean());

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Get the generated PDF file contents
$pdf = $dompdf->output();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

Comment: Esse erro não tem nada a ver com que eu postei. Talvez você tenha que fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: acho que nao sei bem como fazer isto...coloquei o seu codigo no meio do meu ...

Comment: O include que você tem que usar é no seu arquivo php que está querendo transformar em pdf.

Comment: sim mas estou a utilizar o wordpress, ele lê um php template para gerar o html , ou seja tem de ser atravez do url da categoria